# push back to vector of pointers the reference of an object

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class MyClass{
    std::string name;
    int idx;
public:
    MyClass(std::string& name_, int idx_){
        name = name_;
        idx = idx_;
    }
    int get_idx() {return idx;}
    std::string get_name(){return name;}
};
```

What I want to do is to create a vector of `MyClass` instances, and then choose some elements based on a rule, and keep them in another vector, `chosen`. Because both these vectors can have a lot of elements, and the ones in `chosen` would just be copies of the ones in the first vector, I thought I'd make `chosen` a vector of pointers to `MyClass`. This is what I tried:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<MyClass> entries;
    std::vector<MyClass*> chosen;

    std::string name1 = "abc";
    std::string name2 = "def";
    std::string name3 = "ghi";

    MyClass obj_1(name1, 0);
    MyClass obj_2(name2, 1);
    MyClass obj_3(name3, 2);

    entries.push_back(obj_1);
    entries.push_back(obj_2);
    entries.push_back(obj_3);


    for (auto t : entries)
    {
        if (t.get_idx() > 0)
        {
            std::cout << t.get_idx() << ", " << t.get_name() << std::endl;
            chosen.push_back(&t);
        }
    }


    for (auto t : chosen)
    {
        std::cout << t->get_idx() << std::endl;
        std::cout << t->get_name() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

This results in the two pointers in `chosen` to point to the same instance:

```
1, def
2, ghi
2
ghi
2
ghi
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening. In the for loop, `t` are the elements of `entries`, and I'm pushing back their addresses into `chosen`. Why is this happening? Isn't this in spirit similar to doing something as simple as:

```
std::vector<int*> test;

int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int* ptr = &a;
test.push_back(ptr);
ptr = &b;
test.push_back(ptr);

for(auto t : test)
{
        std::cout << *t << std::endl;
}
```

which spits out:

```
5
10
```

Comment: -> `for (auto& t : entries)` else `&t` is pointer to a local(copy of vector element) (leading to dangling pointer).

Comment: You are worried about copies but you should realise that `for (auto t : entries)` means that `t` is a copy too. If you want `t` to b a reference then you need to declare it as such `for (auto& t : entries)`. Seems to be a common beginner failing, treating C++ variables as if they are references when they aren't.

Comment: @john I see. I did consider that, but I'm now unsure as to why I have to do `push_back(&t)` instead of `push_back(t)`.

Comment: what do you mean you are unsure? `push_back(&t)` means you want to add the address of the element `t` to the end of your container. `push_back(t)` on the other hand means you want to add a new element `t` to the end of the container - a copy.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate The `&` operator is needed to form a pointer (in this case from a reference). The multiple uses of `&` in C++ are confusing.